# Java SDK Update Tool "Python runtime could not be found"

Tags: python, jakarta-ee

I'm brand new to java, trying to dive into Java EE and I'm following the instructions here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gexaj.html#gexaa to try to get everything setup.  Unfortunately I'm not able to run the java update tool because I get the error:

```
Update Tool was unable to start.

The Python runtime could not be found.

To fix this problem use the UC_IMAGE_PATH environment variable to provide a path to a valid image.
```

To be clear, I've installed Netbeans at the Java EE 6 SDK and that's as much as I know.  I have a background in PHP so this is a little different.

What piece am I missing?

Comment: Should Python be in the tag list?

Answer (score 1):

check this solution:

http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/update-tool-error

You can also start galssfish server (from NB or .bat file), log into administrator console (web browser: localhost:4848  if You haven't changed default ports) and then run update tool. Works for me, even though the first solution doesn't.

(I know, it's been a year of waiting for the answer, but someone might need this ;) )

Comment: Yeah, I no longer have the problem.  It's been too long I don't know how I fixed it.  It was probably just a symptom of a bigger problem.